# Error when using 'continue reading'

Tags: themes

Using theme 'Twenty Ten' and recently the "Continue reading' at the bottom of a post no longer goes to the text, but ends up on an error page.

Where can we fix this issue?

Comment: What is the error specifically? What does the 'continue reading' link look like - is it the same as it was before (as best you can tell) or has it changed to something else? Is there anything useful in the PHP logs on the server? And if you don't get any useful information from the error or logs, can you try you enabling WP_DEBUG in your wp_config and test again?

Answer (score 2):

Without further info I usually check permalink settings when I see 404s where I would expect it should work.

Go to WordPress Admin > Settings > Permalinks, just loading the admin page should refresh the settings. Recheck the links that were giving you issues.

Comment: Thank you dylanjameswagner; for some reason, someone changed the permalinks settings to some custom structure and added some ' characters, likely using some cut&paste. Cleaning it up, fixed the issue.

Comment: @user162637 Great!